# Future-proof way to specify a MethodInfo via a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I’d like a *future-proof* way of specifying a method via a Linq expression.

I’m designing an API which allows the user to specify a method. For example, client code might look like: `ApiClass<ClientClass>.DoSomething(c => c.ClientMethod)`.

My API is strongly typed. For example,

```
public void DoSomething(Expression<Func<TClientClass, Func<TParams, TResult>>> method){ ... }
```

My question: how can I *correctly* parse the Expression tree to get the MethodInfo specified by the client?

I HAD been using the code below, but it seems that version 4.5 of .NET 4.5 breaks it, by generating a slightly different expression tree. I'd obviously much rather have something which will work for all future versions of C#/.NET

Existing code (similar to answer to SO [Extract method name from expression tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014747/extract-method-name-from-expression-tree)):

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression method)
{
    var lambda = method as LambdaExpression;
    if (lambda == null) throw new ArgumentException("Argument is not a lambda expression (c => c.Thing)");
    var convert = lambda.Body;
    var body = (convert.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        ? ((UnaryExpression)convert).Operand as MethodCallExpression
        : convert as MethodCallExpression;
    if (body == null) throw new ArgumentException("Argument not in correct form (c => c.Thing)");
    var methodInfoValue = body
        .Arguments.OfType<ConstantExpression>()
        .Where(exp => exp.Type == typeof(MethodInfo))
        .Select(exp => (MethodInfo)exp.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (methodInfoValue == null) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot find method name in expression.");
    return methodInfoValue;
}
```

(This code fails on .NET 4.5.1: ends up with a null `methodInfoValue`.)

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166785/lambda-expressions-t-functin-tout-and-methodinfo?rq=1 Though I’m still curious as to a solution which is reasonably future-proof.

Comment: You might want to put up "complete example" to demonstrate this. I can't repro it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution seems to be to use an `ExpressionVisitor` to go through the `Expression` and look for any `ConstantExpression` whose value is a `MethodInfo`, whose `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` is of the correct class…

That appears to work on .NET ≤ 4 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Is this future-compatable? I’m still not sure what I should expect as the scope of reasonable Expression trees which C# might generate.

Anyone from the Microsoft.NET team on here?

Comment: I'm not sure even the .Net Team has time-travelers from the future to answer that.  Snarky reponse aside, don't just assuem you'll upgrade to a newer framework just because time passes. If your code is written for 4.5, then build it for 4.5 unless you verify it'll work on 5.0 or whatever comes next.

Comment: I’m really looking for a best practice for doing this sort of thing, or (informed) comments like "don’t do it this way because .NET reserves the right to change such and such a specific implementation detail". I know that things change, but generally there are more and less future-proofed/portable ways of doing things.